# Manage API calls with Java [Android]

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am trying to manage request calls. Here is my situation. I am using `retrofit 2` with `RxJava`. I have a API request call in `onResume` method in my Fragment. When I switch tabs in my application or rotate the phone the `onResume` method gets called again and if the call is slow I send two same requests and get 2 identical responses. Do you have any idea how I can prevent this?

I would like to not send a second API call if the first one is ongoing or somehow merge the 2 responses into one if the calls are the same.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a boolean flag, which gets checked once after the `onResume()` gets called.

Comment: I don't really like that solution . I would prefer a  more sophisticated way if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a flag for wrapping `api` and make it `false` while requesting and `true` on response

```
private boolean canRequest = true;
void onResume(){
if(canRequest){
   canRequest = false;
   fetchDataUsingRetroFit(new ResponseCallBack(){
       void onResponse(){
         canRequest = true;
       }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using rxJava, the subscribe function will return a subscription object which you can dispose any where(may be in your onPause()), meaning that our activity(or life cycle mananger) will no more bother about the responses after disposal of the subscription object.Now you can expect only the latest response from server...